# How to display node image in page header for custom theme?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'm extending the Tweme theme (a Bootstrap subtheme) and I want the "banner_image" field on the node page to be displayed in the header.

The page.tpl.html template from Tweme has the markup for the header, but this doesn't work because (I believe...) that template doesn't have access to the `$content` variable:

```
print render($content['field_review_nationality']);
```

The node.tpl.html template *does* have access to `$content`, but the header isn't present in that template.

Where/how do I render my "banner_image" field?

Answer (score 1):

You can find @var `$node` on page.tpl.php. you can display your field using this code.

```
<?php 
if(isset($node->field_review_nationality) && !empty($node->field_review_nationality['und'][0]['uri'])) {
   <img src="<?php print file_create_url($node->field_review_nationality['und'][0]['uri']); ?>"/>
} 
?>
```

If you have a style of the image then you can display using below code.

```
<?php print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_review_nationality['und'][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => [STYLE NAME])); ?>
```